# Using grep with negative look-ahead returning no matches

Tags: regex, bash, git, grep

So I am writing a few scripts for migrating SVN to GIT, we have a bunch of "old" branches in SVN that still exist but don't need to be moved to GIT. (Branches which happened to have already been merged to trunk).
After a bit of google-fu I've come up with the following:

```
$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' --merged origin/trunk | grep '(?!origin\/trunk)origin\/.*')
```

To be passed to

```
git branch -D --remote _previouscommandgoeshere_
```

If I run just `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' --merged origin/trunk` I get the following output:

```
origin/IR1091
origin/IR1102
origin/IR1105
...
origin/IR932
origin/Software
origin/trunk
origin/trunk@6792
origin/trunk@6850
```

When I add the `grep` command I get 0 values.

However, https://regexr.com/3ot1t has thaught me that my regexp is doing exactly what I want to do. Remove all branches except for the `trunk` branch.

What is wrong with the regexp/grep? (note I am *not* a linux/grep guru. This is all done in bash that comes with windows git)

Comment: `grep` supports several styles of patterns with options `-E`, `-P`, `-F`, `-G` and the default `-e`. The real expressions may be a bit different from each other and from the one produced by https://regexr.com/3ot1t . Besides, the quotations seem not at the right position in your case.

Comment: @ElpieKay care to explain the issues with the quotations?

Comment: I was wrong about the quotation marks. I missed the leading `$(`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp is right, but `grep` by default does not support PCRE expression constructs like Negative look-ahead `(?!`. You need to enable the `-P` flag to enable the PCRE library, without that it just supports the Basic Regular Expression engine

```
.. | grep -oP '(?!origin\/trunk)origin\/.*'
```

Or use a `perl` regex match on the command line for which no flags need to be set up

```
.. | perl -ne 'print if /(?!origin\/trunk)origin\/.*/'
```

Comment: thanks a lot!, spot on. I just revised my `grep regex` to do the inverse instead (yay for `--help` looked over the `-P` part). Current command: `"c:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -c "echo $(git for-each-ref --format='%%(refname:short)' --merged origin/trunk | grep -v -P 'origin\/trunk$')"` (executing from a jenkins build running windows)

Comment: @DaanTimmer Better to use `'origin\/(?!trunk).*'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

grep -P 'origin/(?!trunk)'
just this, can match what your wanted